# Start activity indicator view in iOS and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

I have some swift code for an iOS app that looks like this:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

 @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
     activity.isHidden = false
     activity.startAnimating()

     [My code]

     activity.stopAnimating()
     activity.isHidden = true
 }
```

But when the function is running the activity indicator doesn't appear, and if I remove:

```
activity.stopAnimating()
activity.isHidden = true
```

It will appear when the function is done, so in some way the activity indicator first appears when the function have finished(?)

So my question is: How do I make the activity indicator view stay active only when the function is running?

Comment: does `[My code]` execute some async calls to API?

Comment: [My code]  is getting a string the user have input and manipulate it